# RegEx positive lookahead in a specific order

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a very specific regular expression.
The pattern should match any string that contains `a` and `b` in this specific order.
There may be possible in-between characters, but not necessarily.

Examples:

```
//Shouldn't match and doesn't 
a
b

//Should match and does 
ab
a.b
aB.
a.b. 

//Shouldn't match, but does  
ba
b.a
Ba.
b.a.
```

The pattern I've built is `^(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b).+$` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GfY2VC/1)) with `g`, `m`, `i` flags.
Is there any way to keep positive lookaheads ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a lookahead pattern here. Simply put `.*` between `a` and `b` to match anything in between:

```
a.*b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GfY2VC/1